# Why can I not set permissions on fresh install of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, centos

A fresh installation of PostgreSQL 9.3 (according to the YUM Installation manual on the PostgreSQL wiki) on CentOS 6 (64-bit) will not grant permissions to any users.

I log in to the postgres user and open psql, then I create a role for my default user:

```
CREATE ROLE <name> WITH PASSWORD '<password>';
```

and then try to grant it privileges on the default postgres database:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE postgres TO <user>;
```

which gives the expected output, but the user does not have any permissions on postgres.
The output of `\dp <user>` is quizically empty as well. Additional testing shows that I cannot give any users permissions. However, when I try to drop a role that has been granted these nonexistent permissions, it says

```
ERROR: role "<user>" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL: privileges for database postgres
```

I am at a loss. I did also check to make sure the postgres Linux user has the appropriate file permissions on the PostgreSQL data directory.

Comment: Use REVOKE before you DROP the role

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "but the user does not have any permissions on postgres" - actually the role has permissions on the DB in question (check with [`has_database_privilege()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE). Not so for the various objects contained in the DB though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're expecting too much of `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE postgres TO <user>;`

`ALL` in this context means that the command is equivalent to:

```
GRANT CREATE,CONNECT,TEMPORARY ON DATABASE postgres TO <user>;
```

And the way you create the ROLE, it cannot login to any database anyway (you can check this with `\du`).
It could if it was created with:

```
CREATE ROLE name WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass';
```

or use `ALTER ROLE name WITH LOGIN` later on.

Starting from this, to give the user permissions to create objects in the database, other forms of `GRANT` should be used.